# Can I get a socket.makefile to have the same read semantics as a regular file?

Tags: python, file, sockets, io

Python file objects have a read method which takes an optional size argument, which is basically the maximum number of bytes to return.  For example:

```
fname = "message.txt"
open(fname, "w").write("Hello World!")
print open(fname).read()   # prints the entire file contents
print open(fname).read(5)  # print "Hello"
print open(fname).read(99) # prints "Hello World!"
```

So even though our file has fewer than 99 characters, a call to `read(99)` returns immediately with all of the available data.

I'd like to get this behavior on the file objects returned from [socket.makefile](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile).  But if I say:

```
import socket
ADDR = ("localhost", 12345)

listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listener.bind(ADDR)
listener.listen(1)

client = socket.create_connection(ADDR)
cf = client.makefile("r+b", bufsize=0)

server, client_addr = listener.accept()
sf = server.makefile("r+b", bufsize=0)

sf.write("Hello World!")
sf.flush()
print cf.read(99)         # hangs forever
```

According to the `socket.makefile` docs, *"The optional mode and bufsize arguments are interpreted the same way as by the built-in file() function."*  But my original file example works even when I say `open(fname, "r+b", 0)`, whereas I can't figure out a way to return all available data up to the specified number of bytes with a socket pseudo-file.

This seems to work perfectly well if I just use `socket.recv`:

```
import socket
ADDR = ("localhost", 12345)

listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listener.bind(ADDR)
listener.listen(1)

client = socket.create_connection(ADDR)
server, client_addr = listener.accept()

server.sendall("Hello World!")
print client.recv(99)           # prints "Hello World!"
```

So is there any way to make this work with `socket.makefile`, or is this kind of "advanced" functionality simply not available?

**EDIT:** Python 3.2 seems to behave correctly, though the argument syntax to `socket.makefile` appears to have changed:

```
import socket
ADDR = ("localhost", 12345)

listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listener.bind(ADDR)
listener.listen(1)

client = socket.create_connection(ADDR)
cf = client.makefile("rwb", buffering=0)

server, client_addr = listener.accept()
sf = server.makefile("rwb", buffering=0)

sf.write(b"Hello World!")
sf.flush()
print(cf.read(99))         # prints "Hello World!"
```

I haven't dug into the source code yet to figure out the difference between these two versions, but that may be a hint.

Comment: @BrandonRhodes I believe this is another viable alternative to closing the socket `sock.shutdown(SHUT_WR)`

Answer (score 27):

The problem here is that `client.read()` tries to read from current position to the `EOF`, but the EOF for the socket appears only when the other side closes the connection. `recv` on the other hand will return any data ready to be read (if there are any), or may block according to blocking and timeout settings.

Compare to this one:

```
import socket
ADDR = ("localhost", 12345)

listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listener.bind(ADDR)
listener.listen(1)

client = socket.create_connection(ADDR)
cf = client.makefile("r+b", bufsize=0)

server, client_addr = listener.accept()
sf = server.makefile("r+b", bufsize=0)

sf.write("Hello World!")
sf.flush()
sf.close()
server.close()
print cf.read(99)         # does not hang
```

Comment: This answer gets it exactly right: the conceptual equivalent of a file EOF is a socket close(); this answer should be accepted.

Comment: If you read only to the data available would it still hang? I figure that once 99 bytes does come in. The read will stop blocking as it is waiting for w/e IO to give it 99 bytes or EOF.